# Drop down menu does not work with Bootstrap version 3.4.1 and Jquery >= 3.0.0

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

According to this [link](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2016/07/25/bootstrap-3-3-7-released/) Bootstrap v 3.4.1 is compatible with JQuery v 3 but after I upgrade JQuery from 2.24 to 3.4.1 the drop down menu stopped working. Here is the code that includes the drop down menu:

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">System <b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Html Editor", "Index", "HtmlEditor")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("App Settings", "Index", "AppCommon")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Image Slider Photos", "ParkingImageSlider", "ReservMain")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Settings for Reservations Page", "AppSettingsWebPage", "ReservMain")</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those "li"s need to have the css class of "dropdown-item".

```
 <li class="dropdown-item">@Html.ActionLink("Html Editor", "Index", "HtmlEditor")</li>
```